# Summarize Two Overlapping Layers Within a Third Layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, expression, arcade

My project has 3 relevant layers, 2 with data I wish to extract and a 3rd representing the geography I need a summary of. Landuse, Field "Use" (values x y z), Soils, Field "Soil Type" (values 1 2 3), and Parcels. The information I am looking for is the total area for every unique combination of Use and Soil Type that overlap spatially. The goal is for the user to click on any given parcel and get a table that looks something like:

| Use | Soil Type | Area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 0.9 |
| x | 2 | 1.6 |
| y | 3 | 2.5 |
| z | 1 | 0.6 |
| z | 2 | 0.7 |
| z | 3 | 3.3 |

Where the total area is the same as the area of the selected parcel.

In its ideal form, this should appear as a popup/feature info panel in a ArcGIS Online Experience (non-enterprise). I've tried using attribute expressions/arcade expressions, but my lack of coding experience shows and the most I have been able to accomplish is a list of all values x y z that appear within the boundary, including repeat values from different polygons.

```
var intersectLayer = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map, "Landuse"),Buffer($feature, -10, 'feet'))
var landUse = ""
for (var f in intersectLayer){
    landUse = concatenate(landUse,f.Use_," ")
}
return landUse
```

If I work offline and use ArcGIS Pro, I have found that running Overlay: intersect of Soils and Use and then running Overlay: intersect of the resulting layer and the parcel layer will give me a layer that I use with the Screening Tool in Web App Builder, but Layer ABC has over 200,000 polygons at that point and running the model can take 10-20 minutes. Doing this after every update to the source layers is doable, but I know it's inefficient and could be done better.

I've looked into creating an hosted layer that would update as the component layers did, but that requires an attribute merge/join rather than a spatial one and all the other tools that sounded promising are only useful on 2 layers.